# Animate width of rectangle automatically at page load (no button press)

Tags: jquery, html, animation, jquery-animate

I am very new to jquery. I am trying to create a simple width animation. I have it working fine if I press a button. However, what I want is for the animation to happen automatically as soon as the page is loaded. I have hunted for an example, but do you think I can find an example that doesn't use a button...

Here's what I have so far:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Anim</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="anim.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="button1">Grow</button>
  <div style="background:green; 
              height:250px; width:1px;
              position:absolute;">

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

anim.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#button1").click(function() {
    $("div").animate({height: '250px',width: '+=300px'},4000);
  });

});
```

How can I trigger the animation without using a button? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you need; **$(document).ready()** This function is used when the page is opened.

**Bring jQuery code like this;**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div").animate({
        height: '250px',
        width: '+=300px'
    }, 4000);
});
```

**You can remove the button from the html code;**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Anim</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="anim.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="background:green;height:250px;width:1px;position:absolute;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div").animate({
        height: '250px',
        width: '+=300px'
    }, 4000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="background:green;height:250px;width:1px;position:absolute;"></div>
```

Comment: Or the shorthand for _$(document).ready(function() {_ is _$(function() {_

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: @sercan-arğa, is there a way to specify which div will be animated. The way it is now, if I add more div blocks, they all animate. How can I specify just the one I want to animate?

Comment: @Lastmboy **I gave you an example:** **https://jsfiddle.net/sercanarga/97cjv5fr/2/**